# Postgres Join on Dynamic Subquery

Tags: join, subquery, amazon-redshift

### Background

I have 2 data tables.

For each row in tableA, I want to find the rows in tableB with the closest dates and join those values onto the row from tableA.

Example tables:

tableA:

| p_id | category | l_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | catA | 2005-01-05 |
| 1 | catB | 2005-06-10 |
| 2 | catC | 2000-01-10 |

tableB:

| p_id | e_id | e_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 2005-01-01 |
| 1 | 23 | 2005-01-06 |
| 1 | 24 | 2005-01-06 |
| 1 | 28 | 2005-01-10 |
| 2 | 29 | 2010-08-10 |

desired result:

| p_id | category | l_date | e_id | e_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | catA | 2005-01-05 | 23 | 2005-01-06 |
| 1 | catA | 2005-01-05 | 24 | 2005-01-06 |
| 1 | catB | 2005-06-10 | 28 | 2005-01-10 |
| 2 | catC | 2000-01-10 | 29 | 2010-08-10 |

### Tried

This query does not work, but I think this is the direction I should be going.

```
select a.p_id, a.category, a.l_date, c.e_id, c.e_date from tableA a 
left join lateral
(
  select top 1 p_id, e_id, e_date from tableB b
  where a.pid = b.pid 
  order by abs(datediff(days, a.l_date, b.e_date))
) c on True;
```

TableA and tableB are massive, 17m and 150m respective rows.

Does this sound like the correct approach?

Using redshift cluster, running postgres 8.x

Comment: Does that query (correlated subquery) run in Redshift?  That looks to be Postgres 9+ SQL.

Comment: Good eye and my bad not being more descriptive!
This query does not run and gives an error; I included it to show an idea of the solutions I have come across.
I'm currently solving this by scripting queries with python, but it takes a very long time (maybe 4 hours split into two jobs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlated subquery approaches or a full cross join approach will all perform the task of comparing every row in one table with every row in the other (in one manner or another).  Comparing (joining) all these rows when the tables get large get prohibitive.  In these cases different approaches are needed.

Brute forcing won't be fast (if it even completes) so we need to be a bit more efficient in going about this.  I tell clients to think about how they would do this query (by hand) if I gave them stacks of index cards.  A person values their time so they don't go about this by making all possible combinations, they would come up with a more efficient way that they can complete quickly and get back to their lives.  In cases like the one you are describing you need to find the more efficient approach.  I'd be happy to talk to you more about building these types of queries.

Taking your data (and sprucing it up a bit for some more interesting cases) I created an example of how you can do this.  (Yes, you could cross join the small tables and do this with simpler SQL but that won't scale.)

Data setup:

```
create table tableA (p_id int, category varchar(64), l_date date);
insert into tableA values
(1,'catA','2005-01-05'),
(1,'catB','2005-06-10'),
(2,'catC','2000-01-10');

create table tableB (p_id int, e_id int, e_date date);
insert into tableB values
(1,22,'2005-01-01'),
(1,23,'2005-01-06'),
(1,24,'2005-06-01'),
(1,28,'2005-06-15'),
(2,29,'2010-08-10');
```

The query looks like:

```
with combined as 
(
  select
    *,
    coalesce(max(l_date) OVER (partition by p_id order by
      dt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), '1970-01-01'::date) cb,
    coalesce(min(l_date) OVER (partition by p_id order by
      dt desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), '2100-01-01'::date) ca 
  from
    (
      select
        p_id,
        category,
        l_date,
        NULL as e_id,
        NULL as e_date,
        l_date dt 
      from
        tableA 
      union all
      select
        p_id,
        NULL as category,
        NULL as l_date,
        e_id,
        e_date,
        e_date dt 
      from
        tableB 
    ) c
)
,
closest as 
(
  select
    p_id,
    e_id,
    e_date,
    cb,
    ca,
    case
      when
        coalesce(e_date - cb, 0) > (ca - e_date) 
      then ca 
      else cb 
    end closest 
  from
    combined 
  where
    e_date is not NULL
)
select
  c.p_id,
  a.category,
  a.l_date,
  c.e_id,
  c.e_date 
from
  closest c 
  left join tableA a 
  on c.closest = a.l_date and c.p_id = a.p_id 
order by
  c.p_id,
  c.e_id ;
```

While this can look like a lot it isn't that complex.  First CTE finds the closest l_date earlier than e_date (cb) and the closest l_date later than e_date (ca).  It does this on on UNIONed set of data to allow for windowing.  The second CTE just determines which is closer, ca or cb, and produces this as "closest".  It also strips out all the tableB information that was added by the UNION (no longer needed).  Lastly this "closest" date provides the join on information needed to build the final result.

Now this query doesn't account of many possible real-world data issues that can happen so take this as a starting point.  I'm also making some assumptions about your data based on the test data (like no 2 rows in tableA will have the same l_date and P_id).  So use this as a starting point.

And a last word on performance - while window functions are not cheap and will do more work as your data tables increase in size, they are orders of magnitude more performant than cross-joining massive tables.  What you are looking to do is complex so will take some time but this is the fastest way I have found perform these complex operations that would normally be a massive loop problem.